# How to Hide Facebook Page Plugin if the User Already Liked the FB Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-likebox

I know about html,css, and javascript so no worries. I want to hide my facebook page plugin if the users already "Liked" my facebook page. Is this possible?

Please help me
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to do that:

> Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins

Also, like gating is not allowed and users should always be able to unlike something at the same place where they liked it.

Comment: yes, it is in the platform policy of facebook. you must read the whole platform policy before using the facebook api or social plugins.

Comment: how about if someone likes or already liked my facebook page then those people who like my page will the only one can view the content? can you give me a code or solution of that?

Comment: _“those people who like my page will the only one can view the content?”_ – that is called Like Gating, and also not allowed any more by Facebook.

Comment: I have a question. If I Like Gate my facebook page, is there any possible that my facebook page will be banned? 

my second question: What happens to my page is I Like Gate it?

Comment: like gating is not allowed. it is pointless to discuss what could happen, not allowed means: "don´t do it". it is not really possible anymore anyway, so forget about it.